# Passing cucumber.options as environment variables in gitlab

Tags: gitlab, cucumber, gitlab-ci

I have cucumber test with some sets of features that are splited by tags. The test can be run in gitlab ci. What I need is to be able to run the specific tests by passing the env variable "cucumber.options". The problem is that I cannot set key that contains "."
I am getting error: "Variables key can contain only letters, digits and '_'"
Can someone help me with this?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cucumber will also recognize properties written in uppercase with `-` and `.` replaced with `_`. So you can use `CUCUMBER_OPTIONS`.

https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/master/core#properties-environment-variables-system-options